# How can I count the number of SQL queries needed to render a Django admin page?

Tags: sql, django, testing, model-view-controller

Part of my django admin site that uses a lot of Inlines is running slowly and [based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640301/django-admin-page-with-inline-model-loads-very-slowly) I think that it might have to do with the number of SQL queries it generates. I'd like to count the number of SQL queries so I can test some changes. I know how to do this on a custom-written view but I can't figure out how to do it for a standard admin view.

Here's how I would test my own view. The view is called `weight_plot` and the app is called `runner`.

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.conf import settings
settings.DEBUG = True
from django.db import connection
import runner.views

myview = runner.views.weight_plot
request = factory.get('/weights')
response = myview(request)

n_queries = len(connection.queries)
```

This works, and now I'd like to see how many queries are needed to load the page at `https://example.com/admin/runner/MODEL_NAME/add/`. But I can't figure out what view to use for this instead of `myview` above.

Comment: Use djabgo debug toolbar https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: U can use https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19556139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) with `'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel'`. You can see each query and how long it takes to execute them.