# Django Admin Inline hit database multiple times

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

```
DjangoVersion:2.1.7
PythonVersion:3.8.2
```

I have a `StoreLocation` model which has ForeignKeys to `Store`, `City` and `Site` (this is the default DjangoSitesFramework model). I have created TabularInline for `StoreLocation` and added it to the `Store` admin. everything works fine and there isn't any problem with these basic parts.

now I'm trying to optimize my admin database queries, therefore I realized that `StoreLocationInline` will hit database 3 times for each `StoreLocation` inline data.

I'm using `raw_id_fields`, managed to override `get_queryset` and `select_related` or `prefetch_related` on `StoreLocationInline`, `StoreAdmin` and even in `StoreLocationManager`, i have tried `BaseInlineFormsSet` to create custom `formset` for `StoreLocationInline`. None of them worked.

Store Model:

```
class Store(models.AbstractBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}] {}'.format(self.id, self.name)
```

City Model:

```
class City(models.AbstractBaseModel, models.AbstractLatitudeLongitudeModel):
    province = models.ForeignKey('locations.Province', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cities')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    has_shipping = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('province', 'name')

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}] {}'.format(self.id, self.name)
```

StoreLocation model with manager:

```
class StoreLocationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('store', 'city', 'site')


class StoreLocation(models.AbstractBaseModel):
    store = models.ForeignKey('stores.Store', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='locations')
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='store_locations')
    site = models.ForeignKey(models.Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='store_locations')
    has_shipping = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # i have tried without manager too
    objects = StoreLocationManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('store', 'city', 'site')

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}] {} / {} / {}'.format(self.id, self.store.name, self.city.name, self.site.name)

    # removing shipping_status property does not affect anything for this problem.
    @property
    def shipping_status(self):
        return self.has_shipping and self.city.has_shipping
```

StoreLocationInline with custom FormSet:

```
class StoreLocationFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = self.queryset.select_related('site', 'city', 'store')


class StoreLocationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StoreLocation

    # i have tried without formset and multiple combinations too
    formset = StoreLocationFormset

    fk_name = 'store'
    extra = 1
    raw_id_fields = ('city', 'site')
    fields = ('is_active', 'has_shipping', 'site', 'city')

    # i have tried without get_queryset and multiple combinations too
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).select_related('site', 'city', 'store')
```

StoreAdmin:

```
class StoreAdmin(AbstractBaseAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name') + AbstractBaseAdmin.default_list_display
    search_fields = ('id', 'name')
    inlines = (StoreLocationInline,)

    # i have tried without get_queryset and multiple combinations too
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('locations', 'locations__city', 'locations__site')
```

so when i check `Store` admin change form, it will do this for each `StoreLocationInline` item:

```
DEBUG 2020-04-13 09:32:23,201 [utils:109] (0.000) SELECT `locations_city`.`id`, `locations_city`.`is_active`, `locations_city`.`priority`, `locations_city`.`created_at`, `locations_city`.`updated_at`, `locations_city`.`latitude`, `locations_city`.`longitude`, `locations_city`.`province_id`, `locations_city`.`name`, `locations_city`.`has_shipping`, `locations_city`.`is_default` FROM `locations_city` WHERE `locations_city`.`id` = 110; args=(110,)
DEBUG 2020-04-13 09:32:23,210 [utils:109] (0.000) SELECT `django_site`.`id`, `django_site`.`domain`, `django_site`.`name` FROM `django_site` WHERE `django_site`.`id` = 4; args=(4,)
DEBUG 2020-04-13 09:32:23,240 [utils:109] (0.000) SELECT `stores_store`.`id`, `stores_store`.`is_active`, `stores_store`.`priority`, `stores_store`.`created_at`, `stores_store`.`updated_at`, `stores_store`.`name`, `stores_store`.`description` FROM `stores_store` WHERE `stores_store`.`id` = 22; args=(22,)
```

after i have added `store` to the `select_related`, the last query for `store` disappeared. so now i have 2 queries for each `StoreLocation`.

I have checked the following questions too:

- [Django Inline for ManyToMany generate duplicate queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40665770/6484831)
- [Django admin inline: select_related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29647418/6484831)

---

#### Problem is caused by `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.label_and_url_for_value()`

as @AndreyKhoronko mentioned in comments, this problem is caused by `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.label_and_url_for_value()` located in `django.contrib.admin.widgets` which will hit database with that key to generate a link to admin change form.

```
class ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(forms.TextInput):
    # ...
    def label_and_url_for_value(self, value):
        key = self.rel.get_related_field().name
        try:
            obj = self.rel.model._default_manager.using(self.db).get(**{key: value})
        except (ValueError, self.rel.model.DoesNotExist, ValidationError):
            return '', ''

        try:
            url = reverse(
                '%s:%s_%s_change' % (
                    self.admin_site.name,
                    obj._meta.app_label,
                    obj._meta.object_name.lower(),
                ),
                args=(obj.pk,)
            )
        except NoReverseMatch:
            url = ''  # Admin not registered for target model.

        return Truncator(obj).words(14, truncate='...'), url
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `get_field_queryset()` on `StoreLocationInline`?

Comment: Hi @SebCorbin , as i know `get_field_queryset` will be used to get fields ordering if any exists, so how it can affect my problem? may you describe?

Comment: I think, these extra 2 queries per `StoreLocationInline` form are made by `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget.label_and_url_for_value` method on raw id widget rendering to title+link.

Comment: hi @AndreyKhoronko ! TNX for Ur response, i have checked that function, it seems U R right! so inline will hit database per object to create title+link. i don't see a way to prevent this functionality. any solution?

Comment: @aasmpro you can write custom widget or inherit from `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` and pass an already loaded from DB instance of `StoreLocation` somehow. And then init your custom widget or field as it shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey It's just a propose, I have no complete and tested solution

Comment: @AndreyKhoronko nice solution, i'm gonna test it and let U know if that worked. anyway tnx, i appreciate Ur response!